# Code Splitting React components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, preact

Im relatively new to React (i'm using preact.js, to be precise) and i am trying to code split out react components using webpack 2.

Im exporting my component as stated in the documentation and i am then `importing` it on load.

```
  import('./components/List').then((List) => {
    render(<List />, document.getElementById('main'));
  });
```

The script loads but i'm not handling the promise callback correctly and finding it hard to see any documentation that shows a working version.

`List` returns the following object:

[image]

Comment: What is coming inside the `then`?

Comment: let me update with a console dump

Comment: Running this code actually returns no error, or anything. Render does nothing.

Comment: Put a debugger in the then and check the arguments value.

Comment: Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'createElement' on 'Document': The tag name provided ('[object Object]') is not a valid name.

Comment: I doubt the issue is in this code. It'd be in List component. Do one thing, change the import to a static import `import List from 'so and so'` and then see if  the rest of the code works. You will of-course need to also remove the `then` part.

Comment: If i do it as a static it works fine, if i move the render aspect into the class it also works fine. I just cant seem to access the List object in the promise.

Comment: Please share a minimally repro code somewhere if possible.

Comment: Im doing some other stuff but this is the general idea, have attached webpacks and babel https://gist.github.com/Tom-Millard/de120f6096de88a04ee1a8aa936c4dbc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw your repo. It looks like that your list component doesn't have a `export default`.
I would add the `default` and inside your `then`, when you handle the promise, I'd do it in this way

```
.then(module => {
   const Component = module.default;
   render(<Component />, document.getElementById('main'))
})
```

Comment: This is sounding good, will try it in my code and update. Cheers